# ReactJS API call from componentDidMount returns index.html as response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api, mern

I have a quite simple ReactJS application. I want to fetch some data from my API on page load. In my `componentDidMount()` function I call my `getData()` method to initialize my state in my application. When I do this the console tells me this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

When I check my network tab I find that the response from my call is the `index.html` page returned to me in plain text. Which I find very strange.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router} from "@reach/router";
import Applications from "./Applications";
import Application from "./Application";
import LogIn from "./LogIn";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            applications: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    //Fetch data from the API and putting it in the state
    async getData() {
        const url = "/api/applications";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            applications: data
        })
    }

    // And so on....
}
```

I have no clue to why this happens - because when I call my API from PostMan everything is all good and dandy. Expected response from DB (worked with call from postman):

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5edfac8b75b2bd3fa477555f",
        "text": "Application for Fullstack Developer",
        "applications": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

The response I received:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Job Applications</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do like this  .

```
const url = "/api/applications";
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ applications: data }));
```

hope this'll help .

Comment: @IncrediblePony if this does ans to your que than please do upvote :)

Comment: I would have worked so I will upvote in nonetheless :) But in this case it was basically just my own brainfart in the end

Comment: Happy to have helped.l :) please consider this as marked so can close this que. Thank you!!

Comment: I cannot mark your answer as the solution to this problem - since it does not fix the issue. But the code you have provided is a more slick and nice way to do it and it would have worked perfectly :) I have posted my own answer to what was really happening and will mark that as correct when I can tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaand MASSIVE BRAINFART...

Of course my application does not return anything. I have my API running as a seperate instance on my machine on a totally different port. So when I want to hit my API I have to specify the full URL not just the `/api/whatever` - In my case the full URL should have been `http://localhost:8080/api/applications`

*NOTE* - The best practie would be to store the base part of the URL in an `.env` file and give it a name such as `URL_BASE=http://localhost:8080` and prepend it to my variable.

```js
let url = process.env.URL_BASE + '/api/applications';
```

That way if you don't set the `URL_BASE` you just get the emty string prepended to the URL. This structure is used with hosting services like Heroku

Comment: Instead of writing localhost everytime you can store it in env file and use it like global in your project.

Comment: This is true - I will add that note to the answer